# omp_get_num_threads() and omp_get_thread_num() returning nonsense

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2015, fortran, openmp

I am just starting out with using OpenMP in Fortran using the Intel Fortran compiler and Visual Studio 2015. In the project properties I have "Fortran -> Language -> Process OpenMP Directives" set to "Generate Parallel Code (/Qopenmp)"

I have a simple program starting as follows:

```
program hellothreads
   integer threads, id
   call omp_set_num_threads(3)   
   threads = omp_get_num_threads()

   print *,"there are",  threads, "threads"
```

This produces

> there are -2147483648 threads

which there certainly aren't. Setting the number of threads seems to work OK though, since:

```
   !$OMP Parallel private(id) shared(threads)
   threads = omp_get_num_threads()
   id = omp_get_thread_num()
   print *, "hello from thread", id, "out of", threads
   !$OMP end Parallel
```

outputs

> hello from thread -2147483648 out of -2147483648
>
> hello from thread -2147483648 out of -2147483648
>
> hello from thread -2147483648 out of -2147483648

and continuing with:

```
   !$OMP Parallel private(id) shared(threads)
   threads = omp_get_num_threads()
   id = omp_get_thread_num()
   print *, "this is thread", id, "of", threads
   !$OMP end Parallel
```

outputs

> this is thread -2147483648 of -2147483648
>
> this is thread -2147483648 of -2147483648

Finally there is *different* weird behaviour if I call the OpenMP functions inside the a "print": e.g.:

```
   !$OMP Parallel private(id) shared(threads)
   print *, "this is thread", omp_get_num_threads(), "of", omp_get_thread_num()
   !$OMP end Parallel
   stop
end
```

Outputs

> this is thread            NaN of            NaN
>
> this is thread            NaN of            NaN

What is wrong with my configuration and/or code?

Comment: If you `use omp_lib` do you get something nicer?

Comment: Yeah, That's fixed it :) The tutorial from which I was working from didn't have that in examples; was it just messed up?
Also can you put that as answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Oh OK, I will accept @Vladimir F 's answer I guess. Since the extra advice about using `implicit none` seems generally helpful and would have got the compiler to tell me that there was a problem

Comment: Yes - the `implicit none` is good advice all round.

Comment: I am really surprised that such a simple answer would acquire so many upvotes. I didn't wan't to steal any credit by any means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `implicit none` in ALL your Fortran programs!!!

After doing that you will realize that the functions are not declared and assumed to be `real`. The nonsense real value is than converted to an `integer` value and stored in your variables which you print.

As @francescalus recommends in the comment, by `use omp_lib` you use a module which contains the correct declarations of the functions and will help you check if you are using them correctly.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if you are working in older Fortran dialects (or even FORTRAN), in which modules and their use does not exist, you should, instead, "include omp_lib.h". (Although it is only "implementation defined" whether such a file exists, decent compilers will provide it!)